# Spring security multiple IPs under the same subnet

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ip

I need to protect resource in my project, I want that only a group of specific IPs to access(the IPs is under the same subnet),
and my security framework is Spring Security.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/tokens**" access="hasIpAddress('XXX.XXX.YYY.YYY')" />
</http>
```

I want allow access to all IPs that have XXX.XXX

I don't want to use OR operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hasIpAddress('XXX.XXX.0.0/16')`. Basically you want to compare only the first 16 bits of the IP address so you instruct the framework to do just that.  If you are wondering where this notation comes from, this is the [CIDR notation for routing information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation) and Spring Security simply supports it.